# Tables are displayed horizontally instead of vertical

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create an table with PHP and HTML which gets the data from a MySQL database.
The problem is that the data is displayed horizontally and not vertical.

```
if (isset($_POST['winneron'])) {
    echo "<tr>";
    while ($printuser = mysql_fetch_array($user)) {
        echo "<th>". $printuser['username'] . "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($printgames = mysql_fetch_array($games)) {
        if ( $printgames ['winner'] == $printgames ['team1'] ) {
            echo "<td><b>". strtoupper($printgames ['winner']) . "</b></td>";   
        }
        else { 
            echo "<td>". strtoupper($printgames ['winner']) . "</td>"; 
        }
    }   
}
```

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your current displayed data? We can hardly make out what's being displayed with the above code.

Comment: `echo "</tr>";` move to after `else { 
            echo "<td>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</td>"; 
        }`

Comment: you forget <tr></tr> in your while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your display to be vertical then you have to put each piece of information into a table row `<tr><td>...</td></tr>`

```
while ($ausgabespiele = mysql_fetch_array($spiele)) {
    if ( $ausgabespiele['sieger'] == $ausgabespiele['team1'] ) {
        echo "<tr><td><b>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</b></td></tr>"; 
    }
    else { 
        echo "<tr><td>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</td></tr>"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no `<tr>` and `</tr>` in your `while ($ausgabespiele = mysql_fetch_array($spiele)) { }`...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **TR** in while

```
 if (isset($_POST['winneron'])) {
        echo "<tr>";
        while ($ausgabeuser = mysql_fetch_array($user)) {
            echo "<th>". $ausgabeuser['username'] . "</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        while ($ausgabespiele = mysql_fetch_array($spiele)) {
           echo "<tr>";
            if ( $ausgabespiele['sieger'] == $ausgabespiele['team1'] ) {
                echo "<td><b>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</b></td>"; 
            }
            else { 
                echo "<td>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</td>"; 
            }
           echo "</tr>";
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the row-tags within the while loop...

```
if (isset($_POST['winneron'])) {
    echo "<tr>";
    while ($ausgabeuser = mysql_fetch_array($user)) {
        echo "<th>". $ausgabeuser['username'] . "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($ausgabespiele = mysql_fetch_array($spiele)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        if ( $ausgabespiele['sieger'] == $ausgabespiele['team1'] ) {
            echo "<td><b>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</b></td>"; 
        }
        else { 
            echo "<td>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</td>"; 
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to create a table row insde the loop. To display vertically you need to place the table cells in rows:

```
while ($ausgabespiele = mysql_fetch_array($spiele)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    if ( $ausgabespiele['sieger'] == $ausgabespiele['team1'] ) {

        echo "<td><b>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</b></td>"; 
    }
    else { 
        echo "<tr><td>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</td></tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
if (isset($_POST['winneron'])) {
    $echo = "<tr>";
    while ($ausgabeuser = mysql_fetch_array($user)) {
        $echo .= "<th>". $ausgabeuser['username'] . "</th>";
    }
    $echo .= "</tr><tr>";
    while ($ausgabespiele = mysql_fetch_array($spiele)) {
        if ($ausgabespiele['sieger'] == $ausgabespiele['team1'])
            $echo .= "<td><b>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</b></td>"; 
        else 
            $echo .= "<td>". strtoupper($ausgabespiele['sieger']) . "</td>"; 
    }
    $echo .= "</tr>";

    echo $echo;  
}
```